# How to put legend outside the plot for a for 2 column plot definition?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

[image]I am trying to plot the legend outside a 2 columns 5 rows, but in this MWE 2 rows example in matplotlib. Turns out the legend to "`lower center`" puts the space between the two plots as well, which is undesirable. Would anyone have any suggestions to correct this? Ideally default space between the two columns is desired.
(have looked at [various examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-outside-the-plot) which are a single plot exmamples, moving around `bbox_to_anchor`, none exists for 2 column ones, atleast to the best of my knowledge)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
r2x =np.arange(1,10,1)
rmx =np.arange(1,10,1)

a0_r2_gp = np.random.rand(9)
a0_r2_mf = np.random.rand(9)
a0_r2_mo = np.random.rand(9)

a0_rmse_gp = np.random.randint(0, 60, 9)
a0_rmse_mf = np.random.randint(0, 50, 9)
a0_rmse_mo = np.random.randint(0, 40, 9)

a1_r2_gp = np.random.rand(9)
a1_r2_mf = np.random.rand(9)
a1_r2_mo = np.random.rand(9)

a1_rmse_gp = np.random.randint(0, 30, 9)
a1_rmse_mf =np.random.randint(0, 20, 9)
a1_rmse_mo =np.random.randint(0, 15, 9)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8, 12) )
axs[0,0].plot(r2x, np.asarray(a0_r2_gp), marker='o', c = gp_color, label='GP')
axs[0,0].plot(r2x, np.asarray(a0_r2_mf), marker='o', c = mf_color, label='MF')
axs[0,0].plot(r2x, np.asarray(a0_r2_mo), marker='o', c = mo_color, label='MO')
axs[0,0].set_xticks(r2x)
axs[0,0].set_yticks(np.linspace(0,1,11))
axs[0,0].set_ylim(0, 1)
axs[0,0].set_ylabel("r\u00b2, 1st case", fontsize=textfs)

axs[0,1].plot(rmx, np.asarray(a0_rmse_gp), marker='o', c = gp_color, label='GP')
axs[0,1].plot(rmx, np.asarray(a0_rmse_mf), marker='o', c = mf_color, label='MF')
axs[0,1].plot(rmx, np.asarray(a0_rmse_mo), marker='o', c = mo_color, label='MO')
axs[0,1].set_yticks(np.arange(10, 65, 5))
axs[0,1].set_xticks(rmx)
axs[0,1].set_ylim(10, 65)
axs[0,1].set_ylabel("%rmse", fontsize=textfs)
fig.suptitle("r\u00b2 and %rmse averages for Tubes", fontsize=textfs)

axs[1,0].plot(r2x, np.asarray(a1_r2_gp), marker='o', c = gp_color, label='GP')
axs[1,0].plot(r2x, np.asarray(a1_r2_mf), marker='o', c = mf_color, label='MF')
axs[1,0].plot(r2x, np.asarray(a1_r2_mo), marker='o', c = mo_color, label='MO')
axs[1,0].set_xticks(r2x)
axs[1,0].set_yticks(np.linspace(0,1,11))
axs[1,0].set_ylim(0, 1)
axs[1,0].set_ylabel("r\u00b2, 2nd case", fontsize=textfs)

axs[1,1].plot(rmx, np.asarray(a1_rmse_gp), marker='o', c = gp_color, label='GP')
axs[1,1].plot(rmx, np.asarray(a1_rmse_mf), marker='o', c = mf_color, label='MF')
axs[1,1].plot(rmx, np.asarray(a1_rmse_mo), marker='o', c = mo_color, label='MO')
axs[1,1].set_yticks(np.arange(6, 30, 2))
axs[1,1].set_xticks(rmx)
axs[1,1].set_ylim(6, 30)
axs[1,1].set_ylabel("%rmse", fontsize=textfs)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0), loc="lower center", bbox_transform=fig.transFigure, ncol=3)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try this: `fig.tight_layout();fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.05);fig.legend(labels=['GP','MF','MO'], loc="lower center", ncol=3)` I think you will find [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55465653/legend-location-in-matplotlib-subplot) helpful.

Comment: I removed the [tag:numpy] tag since your question is about [tag:matplotlib] and has nothing to do with numpy. Please remember that tags should indicate what the question is _about_, not what it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [constrained layout](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html) rather than `tight_layout`.
2. Use a figure legend rather than `plt.legend` (which is a wrapper to `ax.legend`) and set the `loc` to "outside lower center".
3. Only set the labels within one of the axes, otherwise the legend entries will be repeated.

See also https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#figure-legends

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r2x =np.arange(1,10,1)
rmx =np.arange(1,10,1)

a0_r2_gp = np.random.rand(9)
a0_r2_mf = np.random.rand(9)
a0_r2_mo = np.random.rand(9)

a0_rmse_gp = np.random.randint(0, 60, 9)
a0_rmse_mf = np.random.randint(0, 50, 9)
a0_rmse_mo = np.random.randint(0, 40, 9)

a1_r2_gp = np.random.rand(9)
a1_r2_mf = np.random.rand(9)
a1_r2_mo = np.random.rand(9)

a1_rmse_gp = np.random.randint(0, 30, 9)
a1_rmse_mf =np.random.randint(0, 20, 9)
a1_rmse_mo =np.random.randint(0, 15, 9)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8, 12), layout='constrained' )
axs[0,0].plot(r2x, np.asarray(a0_r2_gp), marker='o', label='GP')
axs[0,0].plot(r2x, np.asarray(a0_r2_mf), marker='o', label='MF')
axs[0,0].plot(r2x, np.asarray(a0_r2_mo), marker='o', label='MO')
axs[0,0].set_xticks(r2x)
axs[0,0].set_yticks(np.linspace(0,1,11))
axs[0,0].set_ylim(0, 1)
axs[0,0].set_ylabel("r\u00b2, 1st case")

axs[0,1].plot(rmx, np.asarray(a0_rmse_gp), marker='o')
axs[0,1].plot(rmx, np.asarray(a0_rmse_mf), marker='o')
axs[0,1].plot(rmx, np.asarray(a0_rmse_mo), marker='o')
axs[0,1].set_yticks(np.arange(10, 65, 5))
axs[0,1].set_xticks(rmx)
axs[0,1].set_ylim(10, 65)
axs[0,1].set_ylabel("%rmse")
fig.suptitle("r\u00b2 and %rmse averages for Tubes")

axs[1,0].plot(r2x, np.asarray(a1_r2_gp), marker='o')
axs[1,0].plot(r2x, np.asarray(a1_r2_mf), marker='o')
axs[1,0].plot(r2x, np.asarray(a1_r2_mo), marker='o')
axs[1,0].set_xticks(r2x)
axs[1,0].set_yticks(np.linspace(0,1,11))
axs[1,0].set_ylim(0, 1)
axs[1,0].set_ylabel("r\u00b2, 2nd case")

axs[1,1].plot(rmx, np.asarray(a1_rmse_gp), marker='o')
axs[1,1].plot(rmx, np.asarray(a1_rmse_mf), marker='o')
axs[1,1].plot(rmx, np.asarray(a1_rmse_mo), marker='o')
axs[1,1].set_yticks(np.arange(6, 30, 2))
axs[1,1].set_xticks(rmx)
axs[1,1].set_ylim(6, 30)
axs[1,1].set_ylabel("%rmse")

fig.legend(loc="outside lower center", ncol=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `subplots_adjust` with modern Matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#figure-legends.  Use 'outside lower center' with `layout='constrained'` instead.

EDIT (sorry, cross post with @RuthC below).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, layout='constrained', sharex=True, sharey=True)
np.random.seed(12345)
for n in range(4):
    ax = axs.flat[n]
    ll = []
    for i in range(3):
        l, = ax.plot(np.random.randn(5), label=f'Line {i}')
        ll += [l]

fig.legend(handles=ll, loc='outside lower center', ncol=1, fontsize=8, labelspacing=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]